# Make a bash script available without using ssh

Tags: bash, shell, sh, sudo

I have a simple bash script (myscript.sh).

```
mysqldump -u busql mydb mytable1 mytable2 mytable3 | mysql -u busql mydb2 && rsync --progress --stats -av --chown=mydomain.de:psacln /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/pictures/master/product/1/* /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.de/httpdocs/pictures/master/product/1/
```

So basically the script dumps 3 tables from db1 and insert them into db2, copy all pictures from mydomain.com to mydomain.de and change the user for all copied pictures from mydomain.com to mydomain.de.

Now I want to make this script (one-click) available for my colleagues without giving them ssh access to our server.

First thing I was thinking of, was to make this script through html/php available. But the problem here is that the script needs to be run as root in order to change the user/owner for the copied files. I would like run the script from/with mydomain.com user but open minded. And it seems like there is no **safe** solution to run this script from a php page as root.

Could I maybie give mydomain.com user the rights to change file-owners or what would you suggest to make this script available without ssh access?!

There are also other scripts with other file-owners coming in the future, that need to be easy available for my colleagues. So I thinking what could be here the best solution ...

Comment: I don't believe this belongs on serverfault.com as one user has flagged because it's not really a professional server administration issue rather a unix (software) design issue.  It is arguable that it belongs on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As a very decoupled (and quite ugly) method, you could run a cron-job on your server that checks for the presence of a file and makes the backup if the file is present. Put the file on a shared filesystem, or in Dropbox or anywhere client and server can see it. If the server detects the file, it makes the backup and deletes the file.

Answer (score 1):

`chown` is really a root only operation.  The usual way to change ownership is to allow the target user (`mydomain.de`) read access to the files and then copy the files as that user.  This doesn't require any root access to execute.

You can give access for one specific user to run one specific script as another named user using [`sudo`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) by editing [`/etc/sudoers`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers).

For example, for two users "bob" and "frank", bob can run "/home/bob/special_script.sh" as frank as long as frank has access to the script and this line is added to /etc/sudoers:

```
bob ALL=(frank) NOPASSWD: /home/bob/special_script.sh
```

bob would run:

```
sudo -u frank /home/bob/special_script.sh
```

---

I recommend that instead of rsync with `--chown` you create a script containing the rsync command and give sudo access to run it as `mydomain.de`, giving `mydomain.de` access to read  `/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/pictures/master/product/1/`

Comment: Ok and you would work with access-control-list to grant a certain user access to a directory?